# Word Userform Hotkey

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

I currently use word templates in my business to help create customer mailings. There's a existing userform coding on our templates that insert the proper return address, phone number, legal entity, etc... onto the letter. Lately we've been having issues with a subset of users (seemingly random, we've been through exhaustive testing and cant find rhyme/reason) who do not receive the popup to choose whatever items they need when they enable macros. In testing we've found that the users have been able to go into vbasic and run the userform manually. I'd like to build in a hotkey option to initialize the userform, please help! Currently, the ThisDocument object has this code to run the userform:

```
Private Sub Document_New()

Channel_Select.Show

End Sub
```

From  what I've been able to find online, something like the OnKey Command from excel could be used, but I cant find the Word version. Does anyone have experience in this?

Comment: File/Options, the entry to customize the Ribbon. You'll find the Keyboard Shortcuts button there. That dialog box enables you to assign a keyboard shortcut to any command or macro, just choose the category from the list on the left. Pay special attention to the "container" where this is saved - you'll want to save it in the template with the user form and *not* in the default Normal.dotm. Note, however, that you'll need to create a "plain" macro in a normal module for the keyboard shortcut - the document events in `ThisDocument` will not be accessible for keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on a thread about keybinding, but I can't refind that thread. I added 2 new modules to my document, module1 has:

Option Explicit

```
Sub AddKeyBinding()
    With Application
         ' \\ Do customization in THIS document
        .CustomizationContext = ThisDocument

         ' \\ Add keybinding to this document Shorcut: Alt+r
        .KeyBindings.Add KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeyAlt, wdKeyR), _
        KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryCommand, _
        Command:="TestKeybinding"

End With
End Sub
```

Module 2

```
Option Explicit

 ' \\ Test sub for keybinding
Sub TestKeybinding()
    Channel_Select.Show
End Sub
```

Run the AddKeyBinding macro, then alt+r will launch the userform on the document